# check if method is contributing to permgen memory

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am fighting permgen memory leak bug. I have very limited ability to check running system, so I am forced to wander through source code. In order to reduce area of search I want to find only methods that (probably) consumes memory from permgen region.

E.g. I have root method set that are definitely called. From that set I need to found path to methods that probaly consumes memory from permgen region (i.e. String.intern() is called etc.). Currently I am facing two problems: how to determine if method is consuming permgen space and the second - how can I walk through byte code to follow execution path?

Thanks is advance, any information is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to take a memory dump and then use [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to investigate what class definitions and strings are taking space in the PermGen area.

You could also add the following flags -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled to enable swiping of PermGen area.